# I have sound but no way to change volume - Xubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I have recently installed Xubuntu 20.04 LTS and I noticed something strange. I do have sound and it works well, but I don't have any indicator of volume in the panel.

I tried using alsamixer to change it, but there I see that all the channels are set to 0 and there isn't any volume on any of them:

[image: alsamixer shows no volume]

This is a really odd problem and to be honest I have no idea how to troubleshoot it. Hope that someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the panel and choose *Panel -> Panel Preferences*

Click on the Items tab, check for the PulseAudio Plugin.  If it is not there then click on the + on the right

[image]

Scroll down and find the PulseAudio Plugin and double click it or click the + Add button to add it:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow, that was easy! I didn't know I needed an additional plugin for that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same problem after installing Xubuntu as a second desktop option (to try it out, while not uninstalling Ubuntu). 22.04.1 LTS, by the way.

This plugin did not show up in the "add new items" list without first installing the plugin:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin